# What is the correct way for getting data from this object in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I've got ReactJs who is getting response from backend server. `console.log(content)` is looking like this:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "dataNKS": [
            75670.99,
            75654.97,
            75943.38
        ],
        "dataMNKS": [
            37835.5,
            37827.49,
            37971.69
        ],
        "dataEKS": [
            75871.73,
            75816.11,
            76062.19
        ],
        "dataMEKS": [
            37935.86,
            37908.05,
            38031.1
        ]
    },
    "id": "32083654",
    "descr": "articleno1",
    "price": "75.284",
    "link": "/linkno1",
    "sqm": "75",
    "ppm2": "2151"
}
```

Now in my react app I can easily access to data with `{content.price}` eg. and I will get `75.284`.

Now trouble I've got is when accessing `content.data`. I can access to data and `console.log` it, where data is formatted like this:

```
{dataNKS: Array(3), dataMNKS: Array(3), dataEKS: Array(3), dataMEKS: Array(3)}
```

Now my question is how to access each data and output it? Desired look in React app would be to output value of `dataNKS + dataMNKS` and under it `dataEKS + dataMEKS` eg. `75670 - 37835.5` - this is first entries of arrays `dataNKS` and `dataMNKS`.
I've tried

```js
const a = content.data;
return(
<div className ='container'>
{a.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            {item.dataEKS}
            {item.dataMEKS}
          </li>
        ))}
</div>
);
-------Eror Cannot read property 'map' of undefined----------
<div className='container'>
          {Object.keys(a).map((keyName, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <strong>Name: {a[keyName]}</strong>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
-------Error Cannot convert undefined or null to object-------
```

and few other methods but without success. What is correct way of displaying data from this object?

EDIT:
Requested part of getting content:

```js
const [content, setContent] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      const res = await ArticleService.article(id);
      setContent(res.data);
    };
    fetchPosts();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

and after this I can `console.log(content)`

Comment: The first message is telling you that `a` is undefined after `const a = content.data`. The problem is not in this code.

Comment: @marekful  I think ```.map``` won't work because ```content.data``` is an object but i've tried with ```.map``` anywas. I think that is reason of undefiend.

Comment: Well, `undefined` itself is an object in JS but the message couldn't be clearer. It says content.data is undefined.

Comment: Re: your update, `I can access to data and console.log`, do that just above the line const a = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct in your second code.There are only one error you need to handle:

```
Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

you can resolve it by this:

```
<div className='container'>
 {a&&Object.keys(a).map((keyName, i) => (
   <div key={i}>
     <strong>Name: {a[keyName]}</strong>
   </div>
 ))}
</div>
```

Comment: That's all right。And by the way, this is the reason of the error:  when React first render, there are no data response form the net, so a is undefined at this time. When the data feedback, React re-render the DOM, thus you can get it work.

Comment: one more question. response right now is:
`Name: 75285.0275269.0875556.01
Name: 37642.5137634.5437778.01` but i would like to get first ones together in one line eg. `75285.02 - 37642.51` etc.

Comment: response before was good it was my mistake, i'm sorry

Comment: if i'm not clear enough i would like to acces ```dataNKS, dataMNKS, dataEKS, dataMEKS``` individually rather than all at once, with that i would create desired output on frontend.

Comment: you'd better handle it before render. Like`const [dataArr, setDataArr] = useState()` you can `setDataArr` after the `setContent` line. And you can format `res.data.data` to a easy  way to render. Just like `[{ name: 'dataNKS-dataMNKS', value: [ 75285.02 - 37642.51 ] }]`

Comment: format before render is very common in front-end.

Comment: in this case, you can copy those code under the `setContent(res.data)`:
`const data = res.data.data
const dataArr = []

dataArr.push({
  name: 'dataNKS-dataMNKS',
  value: data.dataNKS.map((item, index) => {
    return item - data.dataMNKS[index]
  }),
})
dataArr.push({
  name: 'dataEKS-dataMEKS',
  value: data.dataNKS.map((item, index) => {
    return item - data.dataMNKS[index]
  }),
})
setDataArr(dataArr)
` 
DON'T forget  `const [dataArr, setDataArr] = useState()`!

Comment: Thank you very much! I only needed to modify return: `return item + '-' + data.dataMNKS[index];` to get desired output. Thanks once again! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`content.data` is an object, not an array, that is why you cannot iterate on it with a `map`.
If you want to access to `dataNKS`, you simply need to write: `content.data.dataNKS`.
Then you get an array, and you can iterate on this.

Comment: then I'm getting ```Cannot read property 'dataNKS' of undefined``` when i try to ```console.log``` it.

Comment: Oh then, it is a problem with your content object, which seems undefined. Can you edit your question, by adding the code where you retrive your content object ?

Comment: added. here is jsfiddle also: https://jsfiddle.net/cngsm95v/

Comment: content already contains content.data, or am I wrong ?

Comment: yep ```data``` is an object inside of content object.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this. 
Check for `undefined/null` before using the data (using `?.` optional chaining and `??` Nullish coalescing operator) 
Get `Object.entries` to use `map` in JSX

```
const a = Object.entries(content?.data ?? {});
return (
  <div className="container">
    {a.map(([key, value], i) => (
      <li key={i}>{`Data Key: ${key}, values: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`}</li>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: yep this works. output is: ```Data Key: kreditNKS, values: [75156.53,75145.92,75336.92]``` how could i now extract each value? (without [] braces)

Comment: try writing value[0],value[1] ... etc